# Swift: Spark action at certain part of song(avaudioplayer)

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am playing a song using AVAudioPlayer and when the song gets to its 30 second mark, i want to spark an action(call a function). I know how to do this when the song is finished like this:

```
func play(url: NSURL) {
let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: item)

let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player.play()
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
// Your code here
}
```

However, I would like to do something similar but when the song has hit 30 seconds. Is this possible? Right now I have to use NSTimers but it's not reliable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is expensive, but it works very well.

First i run a loop that calls "checkForStrobe" a lot:

```
var dpLink : CADisplayLink?
dpLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "checkForStrobe")
dpLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Then I simply put this within my checkForStrobe function:

```
func checkForStrobe(){
    //This is being called repeatedly checking if its time to run strobe
    if(backgroundAudio.currentTime >= 38.5 && backgroundAudio.currentTime <= 38.6){
        runStrobe()
    }
    if(backgroundAudio.currentTime >= 63.5 && backgroundAudio.currentTime <= 63.6){
        stopStrobe()
    }
    if(backgroundAudio.currentTime >= 125.0 && backgroundAudio.currentTime <= 125.1){
        runStrobe()
    }
    if(backgroundAudio.currentTime >= 150.0 && backgroundAudio.currentTime <= 150.1){
        stopStrobe()
    }
}
```

This solved my issue.